# What driving issues does Nuget solves that traditional project references cannot?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm looking for a simple explanation of what specific problem(s) NuGet is solving.  Especially targeted toward developers who were experiencing success with the kiss "Add Reference" mechanism.

For instance the following link states something to the effect that the "problem" is that source checkins don't include project references.  That is not true as far as I know as they are listed directly in the project files which is usually checked in.  Apologies in advance if I misunderstood the statement.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/simplify-package-management-with-nuget/

What payoff warrants such an increase in complexity as now there seems to be multiple sources for references and for a newbie, it is much harder to trace what is happening between 4 (?) typical interacting sources:

- Project references,
- Nuget references at machine.config and
- Nuget packages.config
- App.Config.

Background: This stems from frustration while troubleshooting an issue where someone claimed that that order of Startup tag had to come last within the app.config for some cases.  Another link mentioned that an msi must be run in order to make a particular package useful to other windows programs.

Bonus points for stating what happens when one version is listed in the References but nuget lists a competing version.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to download libraries that aren't are your computer yet? So you can download them simply by typing a line. And it will add a reference right away.

Answer (score 0):

I find it really useful for quickly trying out a package without investing much time.  It quickly adds references and default config parameters, and if I don't like it, it's easy to back it out.  Although on the flip side, once I am using some package that I have custom configured, if I want to upgrade, yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Source files don't include project references. They only include the reference itself. If the reference is somewhere on your hard drive and not included within the project, then it doesn't get checked in. That's why many projects create a dependencies folder in the solution folder, add the dependencies there, and add them to the VS solution in a solution folder, and then reference the dependency. That's the only way they get checked in ever.

Nuget takes away the need to figure out what dependencies you need for a particular package. It keeps track of updated packages and conflicts for you. It can do it with non-.net items as well like bootstrap and jQuery.

It doesn't have any effect on machine.config as these items are only in the current project. That means you can have multiple solutions with different versions of the same package as needed without having to install them locally or add other settings that would have an adverse effect on other solutions.